# Python Scrapy Pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get this to output 2 scraped items per row to a second csv but I can't seem to get the formatting of this line correct. `output_urls` has many scraped URLs in it and for every URL that is in it it should produce a row of output along with the other variable `Urls`.

```
self.file.writelines(["%s,%s\n" % (i, j) for (i, j) in zip([item['Urls']], ["\n".join(item['output_urls'])])])
```

`item['Urls']` contains:

```
websiteinput
```

`item['output_urls']` contains:

```
website1
website2
website3
website4
website5
```

I'm trying to get:

```
websiteinput, website1
websiteinput, website2
websiteinput, website3
websiteinput, website4
websiteinput, website5
```

What it outputs is:

```
websiteinput, website1
website2
website3
website4
website5
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share what `item` looks like? did you mean to use `item['output_urls']` instead of `['output_urls']`?

Comment: Yes, I meant to use `item['output_urls']`. Correcting that causes the `item['Urls']` to show correctly but `item[`output_urls']` is still just showing only one letter. `item['output_urls']` contains links that were scraped. `item['Urls']` contains the input URL.

Comment: It would help if you pasted an sample item with the values of `item['Urls']` and `item['output_urls']`, and the expected output to write to the file.

Comment: @paultrmbrth I have updated my question with more info. Will you please let me know what you think?

Answer (score 1):

the zip method takes two `iterables` of the same size and joins them like so:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [2, 2, 9, 0, 9]

>>> zip(a, b)
[
    (1, 2),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 9),
    (4, 0),
    (5, 9)
]
```

If this is what you want to achieve then

```
self.file.writelines(["%s, %s\n" % (i, j) for (i, j) in zip(item['Urls'],
item['output_urls']))])
```

might give you what you want

```
https://www.inputurl1.com, https://www.outputurl1.com
https://www.inputurl1.com, https://www.outputurl1.com
```

remove the `join`

This is how I tested your your question, I assumed the `urls` and `output_urls` are both arrays, hence;

```
t = ["https://www.inputurl1.com", "https://www.outputurl2.com"]
k = ["https://www.inputurl3.com", "https://www.outputurl4.com"]

print(["%s, %s\n" % (i, j) for (i, j) in zip(t, k)])
```

and the output I get is

```
['https://www.inputurl1.com, https://www.inputurl3.com\n', 
'https://www.outputurl2.com, https://www.outputurl4.com\n']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I perhaps didn't explain it well to begin with but I have updated my question with more info. Will you please clarify what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the input correctly, `item` looks like this:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(item)
{'Urls': ['websiteinput'],
 'output_urls': ['website1', 'website2', 'website3', 'website4', 'website5']}
```

You can simply use list comprehension like so:

```
>>> [[u, o] for u in item['Urls'] for o in item['output_urls']]
[['websiteinput', 'website1'], ['websiteinput', 'website2'], ['websiteinput', 'website3'], ['websiteinput', 'website4'], ['websiteinput', 'website5']]
>>> pprint(_)
[['websiteinput', 'website1'],
 ['websiteinput', 'website2'],
 ['websiteinput', 'website3'],
 ['websiteinput', 'website4'],
 ['websiteinput', 'website5']]
```

Using `.writelines()` you can do:

```
self.file.writelines("%s,%s\n" % (u, o)
                       for u in item['Urls']
                         for o in item['output_urls'])
```